# How to see the SOAP request data what I am sending using JQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, soap

I am using Jquery to create soap request. Following is required envelop for soap request.

```
POST /netforumaiatest2/xweb/secure/netforumxml.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: amstest.aia.org
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://www.avectra.com/2005/Authenticate"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Authenticate xmlns="http://www.avectra.com/2005/">
      <userName>string</userName>
      <password>string</password>
    </Authenticate>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I wrote the code in jquery

```
var soapMessage='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><Authenticate xmlns="http://www.avectra.com/2005/"><userName>user</userName><password>pass</password></Authenticate></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>';

    $.ajax({
    url: productServiceUrl,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    data: soapMessage,
    complete: endSaveProduct,
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
           });
```

but in endSaveProduct, i am getting `status = error`. How can i see the data what i am sending by `$.ajax call`. please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, what i required. I want to print the response for HTTPRequest that is done here.

```
function endSaveProduct(xmlHttpRequest, status)
            {
              $(xmlHttpRequest.responseXML)
                {
                    alert(xmlHttpRequest.responseText);
```

error is resolved by adding action in the soap request header

```
$.ajax({
                       url: productServiceUrl,
                       type: "POST",
                       beforeSend: function (xhr){
                       xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "URL/Authenticate");
                       //alert("in before send");
                       },
                       dataType: "xml",
                       data: soapMessage,
                       complete: endSaveProduct,
                       contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
                       }).done(function () {alert("calling Authenticate");})
                .fail( function() {alert("fail");});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `beforeSend` option and console log the data :
`beforeSend: function(data) {console.log(data);}`

Comment: I am using xcode but i am not getting any output in console of xcode.

Comment: You should go with what OptimusCrime says, it's more sound.

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you to do this another way. Make a ajax-call to a PHP-file (or aspx) and make the SOAP-call there. You can do so much more with soap in those languages compared to what javascript is capable of.

If you decide to go for PHP I found this lovely class-override a while back:

```
class SoapClientDebug extends SoapClient {
    public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version) {
        print_r($request);
        return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version);
    }
}
```

And simply change:

```
$client = new SoapClient('foo.wsdl');
```

With

```
$client = new SoapClientDebug('foo.wsdl');
```

Comment: Is it possible using javascript only(phonegap + JQuery).

Comment: Sure, you could. But I still think sending SOAP-requests is better in PHP/aspx than javascript.

Comment: My app is in the client side then how can it use PHP. Actually i want to see what xml has generated by my client app in client console.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/version.asp) to check your requests ans responses.

Comment: I am using osX. Please suggest any tool for ubuntu too.